# How to manually set the template of Django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

In a Django project, I have the following form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field_1 = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, required=False)
    field_2 = forms.ChoiceField(
        initial='choice_1',
        choices=(
            ('choice_1', 'Choice 1'),
            ('choice_2', 'Choice 2'),
            ('choice_3', 'Choice 3')
        )
    )
```

In the template, I am simply calling the form using `{{ form }}`. The form gets rendered using browser default. However, I do have a very exact HTML markup in mind for the form. Its something like this:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <div class="form-field">
        <div class="my-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="field-1" value="">
            <label for="field-1">Field 1 (Recommended)</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="field-2" class="required">Field 2</label>
        <select class="my-select" id="field-2" required="required">
            <option value="choice_1" selected="selected">Choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice_2">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice_3">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I am struggling with is adding the wrapping containers for the fields, and also how to set the default value for field 1 (which should be checked by default). How can I do this using Django? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. You can render the form even more dynamically by defining each field itself. Use Django [built-in template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/) to render the form to your needs like so:

```
<div id="form-wrapper">

    <form method="POST" class="post-form" id="form-id">
     {% csrf_token %}

        <div id="field_1">{{ form.field_1 }}</div>
        <div id="field_2">{{ form.field_2 }}</div>

    </form>
</div>
```

That way you can assign individual css `ids` and `classes` to style it as required.